# Copy files based on a list stored in .txt file

Tags: r, list, copy

I have a source folder 
Destination folder 
List of files I want to be copied from source folder to destination folder, which has been saved to a .txt file

listtocopy.txt is as below - not sure if it's important but they are Anabat ZC files.

```
S5281925.35#
S5282317.26#
S5290100.39#
S5281859.28#
S5281932.18#
S5290420.20#
```

I do not want all files to be copied.

I'm new to R -this is what I have so far - but it's not working. I think it's not recognizing the list as a 'list' of file names.

```
# Copy based on list
# identify the folders
current.folder <- "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11"
new.folder <- "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Scan_outputs"

#read listtocopy and assign to list
list<-read.delim("H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Scan_outputs/listtocopy.txt")

# copy the files to the new folder
file.copy(list, new.folder)
```

Comment: How are the file names stored in the txt file? Could you show us the first few lines of `listtocopy.txt`?

Comment: I think a similar question was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893525/save-each-element-of-a-list-to-text-file/51893681#51893681

Comment: apologies it is above now

Comment: @milan I was trying to use info in that post but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a problem with how the text file was being read?? 
anyway, this works. thanks to all that answered.

```
# identify the folders
current.folder <- "C:/Users/Amanda/Desktop/testcopy/Anabat7_11"
new.folder <- "C:/Users/Amanda/Desktop/testcopy/Scan_outputs"

# find the files that you want
list_of_files <- read.delim("listtocopy.txt",header = F) 

#check
print(list_of_files)

#copy vector
setwd(current.folder) 
for(i in list_of_files)
{
  file.copy(i, new.folder)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
setwd(current.folder) 
for(i in list_of_files)
{
file.copy(i, new.folder)
}
```

`file.copy()` doest work with vectors, thats why you have to use `for`. 
You can use `setwd()` if list_of_files contains just file names and not paths (file.txt, file2.txt,...)

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but adding for completeness. `file.copy()` now works with vectors (if it didn't before). To copy all files from your list object to a new directory:

```
# Sample data
list <- read.table(text = "S5281925.35#
S5282317.26#
S5290100.39#
S5281859.28#
S5281932.18#
S5290420.20#", header = FALSE)

# Add full path to file names
list$paths <- paste0("H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/", 
                     list$V1, 
                     ".zc")

list$paths
[1] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5281925.35.zc"
[2] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5282317.26.zc"
[3] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5290100.39.zc"
[4] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5281859.28.zc"
[5] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5281932.18.zc"
[6] "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Anabat7_11/S5290420.20.zc"

# Copy files to new directory
file.copy(list$paths, "H:/Documents/1_PhD_Network/Auto_ID/Scan_outputs")
```